# Using JmesPath to filter CloudTrail logs

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, boto3, jmespath

I am working on a boto script to filter out cloudtrail using JmesPath.
JmesPath should give the output as the name of the bucket. I am not sure what should be the right syntax for that. Thanks in advance.

```py
logs = cloudtrail.create_trail(
  Name='GoodTrail',
  S3BucketName='goodbucket3',
)
print(logs)
        
path = jmespath.search('logs',{'S3BucketName': ''}})
print(path)
```

This is what `print(logs)` gives:

```json
{
    "Name": "GoodTrail",
    "S3BucketName": "goodbucket3",
    "IncludeGlobalServiceEvents": true,
    "IsMultiRegionTrail": false,
    "TrailARN": "arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:trail/GoodTrail",
    "LogFileValidationEnabled": false,
    "IsOrganizationTrail": false,
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "520fdfae-02ea-4695-857c-c47c7bcb00dd",
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "x-amzn-requestid": "520fdfae-02ea-4695-857c-c47c7bcb00dd",
            "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
            "content-length": "242",
            "date": "Fri, 18 Dec 2020 15:48:26 GMT"
        },
        "RetryAttempts": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `print(logs)` give you?

Comment: A great resource of this question is the [jmespath website](https://jmespath.org/). Paste your JSON into the text field, then experiment with query syntax until you get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three major issues in this line:

```python
path = jmespath.search('logs',{'S3BucketName': ''}})
```

1. When using the JMESPath `search` function, you have to give the expression as first parameter and the JSON document as second parameter, when you are doing the opposite here.

   > ```
   > search(<jmespath expr>, <JSON document>) -> <return value>
   > ```

   <sup>*Source: https://jmespath.org/specification.html#jmespath-specification*</sup>
   So you should rather have:

   ```python
   path = jmespath.search('some-search-experssion', some_variable)
   ```
2. Your are passing a string `'logs'` to the `search` function and not the variable `logs` containing the JSON document itself, so it should rather be

   ```python
   path = jmespath.search('some-search-experssion', logs)
   ```
3. To search a simple object like you have, you just need to reference the key of the object right away, so your search expression should simply be: `S3BucketName`

   ```python
   path = jmespath.search('S3BucketName', logs)
   ```

---

So, all together, with the script *test.py*:

```python
import jmespath

logs = {
    "Name": "GoodTrail",
    "S3BucketName": "goodbucket3",
    "IncludeGlobalServiceEvents": True,
    "IsMultiRegionTrail": False,
    "TrailARN": "arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-1:562922379100:trail/GoodTrail",
    "LogFileValidationEnabled": False,
    "IsOrganizationTrail": False,
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "520fdfae-02ea-4695-857c-c47c7bcb00dd",
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "x-amzn-requestid": "520fdfae-02ea-4695-857c-c47c7bcb00dd",
            "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
            "content-length": "242",
            "date": "Fri, 18 Dec 2020 15:48:26 GMT"
        },
        "RetryAttempts": 0
    }
}

#print(logs)

path = jmespath.search('S3BucketName', logs)
print(path)
```

Gives:

```
$ python3 test.py 
goodbucket3
```